# Render dynamic page in React.Js with GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, api, dynamic, graphql

I'm stuck on **trying to build a blog**, and I have no idea **how to fetch specific data from GraphQL API to a dynamic page.**

**What I try to build:**

There's a page called /blog with multiple Card Components. Each card is made of an image, a title and a datePosted. Each of these Cards is a Blog Post. When a user tries to click on a blog post, it clicks on a card and it's being taken to a page like */blog/posts/*slug here**. So far so good.

**The issue:**

I have **no idea how to make a page dynamic and fetch the specific data from the blog post that has been clicked to a page that can be dynamic**. I figure I need to use useParams in React.Js or something like that, but I have no idea how to get the specific post that's been clicked. I can only get all of them.

**The code:**

**1) The /blog page (where I fetch all the posts - this is working properly):**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Blog.styles.scss';
import {GraphQLClient, gql} from 'graphql-request';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const graphcms = new GraphQLClient('https://api-eu-central-1.hygraph.com/v2/cl66hwcamapj001t76qqlhkl8/master');

const QUERY = gql`
  {
    posts {
      id,
      title,
      datePublished,
      slug,
      content{
        html
      },
      coverPhoto{
        url
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Blog = () => {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const {posts} = await graphcms.request(QUERY);
      setPosts(posts);
    }
    
    getPosts();
  }, [])


  return (
    <div className='blog-container'>
      <div className='posts-wrapper'>
        {posts && posts.map((post) => (
          <div className='blog-card'>
            <Link to={'/posts/' + post.slug}>
              <div className='blog-card-img-container'>
                {post.coverPhoto && <img src={post.coverPhoto.url} alt='blog-card-cover-img'/>}
              </div>
              <div className='blog-card-title-container'>
                <h1 className='blog-card-title'>{post.title}</h1>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Blog
```

**2) The dynamic page that should display ONLY the post that has been previously clicked ->**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import {GraphQLClient, gql} from 'graphql-request';

const graphcms = new GraphQLClient('https://api-eu-central-1.hygraph.com/v2/cl66hwcamapj001t76qqlhkl8/master');

const QUERY = gql`
  query Post($slug: String!) {
    post(where: {slug: $slug}) {
        id,
        title,
        slug,
        datePublished,
        content{
            html
        }
        coverPhoto{
            url
        }
    }
  }
`;

// const SLUGLIST = gql`
// {
//     posts {
//         slug
//     }
// }
// `;

const BlogPost = () => {

    const {slug} = useParams();
    
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const getPost = async () => {
            // const slugs = await graphcms.request(SLUGLIST);
            
            const data = await graphcms.request(QUERY);

            setPostData(data);
          }
          
          getPost();
    }, [slug])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(postData);
    }, [postData, slug]);

  return (
    <div>BlogPost</div>
  )
}

export default BlogPost
```

**3) The Routes page:**

```js
function App() {
  return (
   <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Navbar />}>
      <Route index element={<Homepage />}/>
      <Route path='/despre-noi' element={<DespreNoi />} />
      <Route path='/galerie' element={<Galerie />}/>
      <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path='/blog' element={<Blog />} />
      <Route path='/animatori' element={<Animatori />} />
      <Route path='/ursitoare' element={<Ursitoare />} />
      <Route path='/oglinda-magica' element={<OglindaMagica />} />
      <Route path='/loc-de-joaca' element={<LocDeJoaca />} />
      <Route path='/posts/*' element={<BlogPost />} />
      

    </Route>
   </Routes>
    
  )
}

export default App;
```

**NOTE:** I know the styles and everything is not refined yet, I'm just trying to get it to work. Any help would be much, much appreciated! **Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

Can't actually run your example to see fully what's up but I did notice these 2 things:

1). You want to setup the routes to be based so that you can grab the post id/slug from the url. In react-router this can be done with `path=":id"` syntax.

```
<Route path="posts" >
  <Route path=":slug" element={<BlogPost />} />
</Route>
```

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route

2). Graphql request needs to send the slug along as a variable.
The `query Post($slug: String!)` expects to be given the slug as a variable.

```
const variables = {
    slug: slug
}

const data = await graphcms.request(QUERY, variables);
```

Example:
https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request#using-graphql-document-variables

Comment: PS you'll probably get way more helpful answers if you can narrow down the question to ask why something specifically isn't woking. (ie. Why can't I grab slug from url?)